# Is it possible to divide a number with string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Actually am trying the following one like..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>A number divided by a non-numeric string becomes NaN (Not a Number):</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = "10";  //typeof d is string
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 100/d; 
// or document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 100/"10";
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT its giving me like..

```
A number divided by a non-numeric string becomes NaN (Not a Number):

10
```

Please explain me why its coming like this.

Thanks..

Comment: "10" is not a non-numeric string, "AA" would be a non-numeric string.

Comment: What do you want to see in output?

Comment: then output has to come NaN. But its giving 10. Thats my problem? @MiChael

Comment: No, it should not come NaN. "10" IS a numeric string.

Comment: am expecting output as NaN. beacause typeof "10" is string @serkan

Comment: if you want to see Nan,  put "Ten",  because that's not convertable to a number.

Answer (score 4):

Unary operators will attempt to convert the string to a number. It will only produce NaN if the string cannot by converted to a number.

You'll notice the same if you try the following, which will convert from hex to 10:

```
100/"0xA"
```

Answer (score 2):

If one of the operands is a string, JavaScript will try to convert it to a number first (ie: "5" becomes 5), or if unsuccessful, NaN is returned for the expression.

This is the reason why 100/"10" gives 10 and not NaN.

Comment: Thank you @Niranjan Borawake

Answer (score 0):

add `+` to convert the variable to a number:

```
var d = "10";  //typeof d is string
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 100 / +d;
// -----------------------------------------------^--
```

And for the opposite, you can do a `typeof` check:

```
if (typeof d !== 'number') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: he kind of wants the opposite I think, he WANTs it to be NaN